# 97 altima 5spd sputters, has loss of power under 3500rpm, dies when clutch is disengaged

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, nissan

My 97 altima has been to the same shop four times for the same problem. It will sputter and smoke( black smoke) and has large loss of power under 3500rpms and dies just about every time you depress the clutch pedal. The idle is very rough just about all the time. When taken to the shop they had replaced the throttle position sensor, the egr valve gasket and the egr valve, the vehicle speed sensor, the distributor and the cap and rotor, the knock sensor, and the spark plugs. Since then the car still acts like it did before it was at the shop. Now it has error codes p0100( mass or Volume air flow A circuit) and 2 p0325( knock sensor circuit (bank 1)). 
Now I've heard that it could be a bad mass air flow sensor..... how do I solve these problems and fix my car so it runs like it should and not like an overgrown golfcart with a horrible idle problem???

Comment: What were the error codes, if any, when your mechanic replaced all those other parts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like a faulty mass airflow sensor.  These are relatively cheap to replace.

Also, check the electrical connector to make sure its attached to the MAF and hasn't somehow worked its way loose.

There is the possibility that your MAF might be dirty - 
You can also try cleaning it with this: 
[http://www.amazon.com/CRC-05110-Mass-Sensor-Cleaner/dp/B000J19XSA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J19XSA)